# Scaffolding feature in Codeigniter 2.02

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Scaffolding feature was in `routes.php` `($route['scaffolding_trigger'] = '';)`in previous version but it is not in routes now in 2.02 so please tell my how do i use scaffolding feature in 2.0.2 version of codeigniter

Comment: Have you tried this? http://git.io/dV8HCQ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scaffolding was deprecated as of at least 1.7, and is removed in 2.0. There is no such functionality out of the box in this version.

Comment: So i think that i am using old tutorial so please refer me any updated tutorial if u can

Comment: There is no updated tutorial. Scaffolding does not exist in CI2.0. If you wish to use it, you should downgrade the version.

Comment: actually i am watching video tutorial which i downloaded from codeigniter's offical site

Comment: If you are referring to the [blog in 20 minutes](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/blog/) tutorial or the hello world one, then they are extremely outdated.

Answer (score 2):

With scaffolding being deprecated, if you absolutely need a solution for this, give [Sparkplug](http://code.google.com/p/sparkplug/) a try.

From the link: "A scaffolding library inspired by Ruby on Rails scaffolding. Adds the ability to generate basic CRUD functionality for any given database table."